# parsing cookie values to if/elseif in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, if-statement

So I have a simple session cookie retriever and am writing the cookie values to the page. There are only two values, "Yes" and "No", otherwise it returns null. Currently, it checks if there is a value, and if so, writes that value to the page. How do I tell the script to write the value conditionally (i.e., writing "Yes" because the value was "Yes", same for "No", instead of just passing the response along) instead of if it exists or not?

```
<script>
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
};
</script>

...

<p>
Response 1: 
<script>
var res1 = readCookie('res1')
if (res1) {
    document.write('res1')
}
else {
document.write("You did not respond.")
};
</script>
</p>
```

Comment: So u want to return Yes if its yes and No if its no rite?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
      "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
    ))
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined
}

document.write(getCookie('res1') != undefined ? 'res1' : 'You did not respond.')
```

Comment: That's getting me closer, but not quite what I'm looking for. The problem is I need to be able to change whatever document.write is for a specific value.

Even though this doesn't work, here's more like what I want to do:
`if (res1) c = "Yes" {
    document.write("Yes")
}
else if (res1) c = "No" {
    document.write("No")
}
else {
document.write("You did not respond.")
};`

Comment: you have value of Cookie variable `res1`. When variable is not exist, res1 will be undefined. What problem to write condition as you want?

Comment: Sorry, `res1` is not the variable, it's the name of the cookie. The variable is being parsed by `readCookie(name)` -- so I would call `readCookie(res1)` and it would return the value of `res1`. But I need to set conditionals for different values.

Comment: `res1 = readCookie('res1'); if(res1 == 'Yes'){}else if(res1 == 'NO'){} else {}`

Comment: Thank you. I knew there was a way to do it, but I couldn't get the syntax right.